# How to configure the maven taglist plugin that small and big letters will be ignored during search keywords?

Tags: java, maven

How can I configure the maven `taglit` plugin to support case insensitive search execution?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <tags>
            <tag>TODO</tag>
            <tag>FIX</tag>
            <tag>FIXME</tag>
            <tag>@todo</tag>
            <tag>@deprecated</tag>
        </tags>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For version 2.4, you can specify the `<matchType>ignoreCase</matchType>` configuration like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglist-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <emptyComments>true</emptyComments>
        <tagListOptions>
            <tagClasses>
                <tagClass>
                    <displayName>Codes Review</displayName>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>
                            <matchString>todo</matchString>
                            <matchType>ignoreCase</matchType>
                        </tag>
                        <tag>
                            <matchString>fixme</matchString>
                            <matchType>ignoreCase</matchType>
                        </tag>
                    </tags>
                </tagClass>

                <tagClass>
                    <displayName>Deprecated Codes</displayName>
                    <tags>                        
                        <tag>
                            <matchString>deprecated</matchString>
                            <matchType>ignoreCase</matchType>
                        </tag>
                    </tags>
                </tagClass>
            </tagClasses>
        </tagListOptions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

UPDATE:

Keep in mind that according to the [doc](http://mojo.codehaus.org/taglist-maven-plugin/faq.html), a tag will only be picked up if it is preceded by either a `*` or `//`. In other words, it has to be inside a single-line or multi-line JavaDoc comments. So for your `@Deprecated` example, this should work:

```
// @Deprecated
public void deprecatedMethod(){ ... }
```

Whereas this won't:

```
@Deprecated
public void deprecatedMethod(){ ... }
```

Comment: I have created a @Decrecated Annotation, but the maven plugin doesn´t find this annotation? But why? I have tried <matchString>@Deprecated</matchString><matchType>exact</matchType>

Comment: @Marwief Try remove the `@`, and use just `Deprecated`.

Comment: @Marwief I have updated my answer with examples on what the Java codes should look like. Also, included the `<encoding>` and `<emptyComments>` configurations to the `pom.xml`. See if that works.